# if $f$ is positive and monotone then $f(x)=o(\int_1^x f(t) d t)$ implies $f(x)^{1 / 2}=o(\int_1^x f(t)^{1 / 2} d t)$

Tags: integration, inequality

> Suppose $f(x)$ is defined on $[1, \infty)$ and is positive. Assume
> that $f$ is monotone and $f(x)=o\left(\int_1^x f(t) d t\right)$
> when $x \rightarrow \infty$ (little o). Prove that $f(x)^{1 /
>  2}=o\left(\int_1^x f(t)^{1 / 2} d t\right)$ when $x \rightarrow
>  \infty$.

Here is my attempt: If we can show that
$$
\frac{\sqrt{\int_1^xf(t)dt}}{\int_1^x\sqrt{f(t)}dt}
$$
is bounded as $x\to\infty$ then
$$
\left(\frac{\sqrt{f(x)}}{\int_1^x\sqrt{f(t)}dt}\right)^2 = \frac{f(x)}{(\int_1^x\sqrt{f(t)}dt)^2}=\frac{f(x)}{\int_1^xf(t)dt}\frac{\int_1^xf(t)dt}{(\int_1^x\sqrt{f(t)}dt)^2}\to 0
$$
as $x\to\infty$, and then we are done. For this, I tried Hölder's inequality
$$
\int_1^x \sqrt{f(t)}dt\leq \left(\int_1^x f(t)dt\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_1^x 1 dt\right)^{1/2} = \sqrt{x}\sqrt{\int_1^x f(t)dt},
$$
which does not work.

Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: Is $f$ monotone increasing or decreasing, or are you considering both scenarios? In case $f$ is monotone increasing (i.e., non-decreasing), then we can proceed as follows: $$f(x)^{1/2}=\frac{f(x)^{1/2}}{\int_{1}^{x}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t}\left(\int_{1}^{x}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right)\leq\frac{\color{red}{f(x)^{1/2}}}{\int_{1}^{x}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t}\left(\int_{1}^{x}f(t)^{1/2}\color{red}{f(x)^{1/2}}\,\mathrm{d}t\right).$$ Combining the two $f(x)^{1/2}$'s and then using the assumption $f(x)=o\left(\int_{1}^{x}f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right)$ proves the desired relation.